# Using Axios to communicate between pods in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, axios

I'm trying to get pods in a cluster to communicate using a REST API.  Our services are Node.js-based.  We formerly used the `request` networking package, but since it is now deprecated, we are migrating to the Axios network package.

The error I'm currently getting is:

`tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443`

When we were using the `request` package, we would send a network request with the following command:

```
request({
  'url': 'https://other-service:8000/api/endpoint',
  'json': true,
  'method', 'post',
  'body': data,
  'auth': {
    'username': '<username>',
    'password': '<password>',
    sendImmediately: true
  },
  'cert': certificate,
  'key': privateKey,
  'strictSSL': false,
  'headers': {
    'username': '<username>'
  }
});
```

Now, with Axios, the command we issue is:

```
axios({
  url: 'https://other-service:8000/api/endpoint',
  method: 'post',
  responseType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'username': '<username>'
  },
  auth: {
    'username': '<username>',
    'password': '<password>',
  },
  data: data,
  httpsAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttps({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
  }
});
```

We are now getting the tunneling error:

`tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443`

I'm guessing the issue is related to where the tunnel package is attempting to validate the certificate, because if I comment out the line containing `httpsAgent`, I then get an error saying the certificate has expired.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your pods running (`kubectl get pods` command)? Could you ping them (from pod to the pod, you can exec into pod using [`kubectl exec` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/))? Are you using any [CNI plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/)?

Comment: @MikolajS. - Yes, the pods are running.  The cluster's health is OK.  I think this likely not a Kubernetes problem, as I'm able to use the `request` library for communication and everything works just fine.  It's only when I use Axios that I run into trouble.